# LDO Outputs wrong voltage

Tags: output, ldo, stability

I am working with a very low profile LDO, [TCR5RG18A](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/Toshiba_01072021_TCR5RG_datasheet_en_20210106-1951921.pdf) and I'm having issues at the regulators output. It's outputting 0.9V which is half its nominated value (nominal value = 1.8V)

The LDO is operated at no load (I've attached the schematic below).

At the input I have two capacitors in parallel, one which is 1uF[0402] (GMK105CC6105KV-F) and the other being a 0.1uF[0603] (MC0603B104J160CT).The same capacitors are placed at the output.

I am assuming there might be an issue with the feedback loop stability so:

- I tried replacing the output capacitors with a 2.2uF electrolytic one (didn't work)
- I tried placing a 1 ohm series resistor to the output electrolytic capacitor (didn't work)
- I tried placing a 22uF electrolytic capacitor in series with a 5 ohm series resistor (didn't work)

And I'm really running out of ideas.

I have exactly the same circuit with TCR5RG33A (the 3.3V of the LDO) and it works perfectly.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Would there be any other reason for the LDO to have wrong output apart from LDO stability or Load issues (although i'm testing it without a Load)

Note:
The datasheet doesn't specify necessary ESR for stability

[image: Schematic Layout]

[image: PCB Layout]

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you have the 1.8V version and not the 0.9V version? What is the input voltage, PVIN?

Comment: Any chance you soldered the part on rotated 90 or 180 degrees?

Comment: Are you sure there's no load?  You don't have a failed cap or maybe a solder bridge???   Many/most modern regulators will 'fold back' if they are asked to provide more current/power than they can handle.  They do this by reducing the output voltage level (or just shutting down).   Consider that all else being equal, your 3.3V version doesn't have to drop as much power as the 1.8V version --  theres a ( (3.3-1.8) * load current ) difference in the amount of power the two would be required to handle.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site and a big thank you for making the effort to start really well here. This is an excellently-written question: detailed, clear and concise. A great example of solid electronics engineering. Upvoted.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson I checked the component N| marking under a microscope and it seems to be the correct one.

Comment: . -td127 If it was rotated the ENABLE pin would be unconnected or below the threshold voltage thus the LDO would be off -Kyle B I don't have a load as this LDO only connects to a touch screen digitiser which I have unplugged -Tony M, thanks, I try to do my best. Note: I was also checking the LDO output under an oscilloscope and I couldn't detect any extreme voltage ripple. Maximum was 80mv p-p

Comment: Try reflowing in case there's a small short or bad joint. If that doesn't work, replace it. Bad parts happen. Also, there isn't much point in paralleling a 0.1uF 0603 with a 1uF 0402. The 0402 should be doing most of the work, yet you've put it further away where it will be less effective.

Comment: Can you probe the output with an oscilloscope ? Did you inquire with the manufacturer ?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm deeply sorry for wasting everyones time. -td127 Bing Bing Bing! I took a second look using the oscilloscope. The component was rotated 90 degrees in the wrong orientation! Once I get my new boards back I will post if the issue is fixed

Comment: Circuit pictured above works fine. Removing the 0.1uF is also fine (depending on how much current your application draws and at what speed)